# Ember app `setTimeout` not working on screen display turned off

Tags: javascript, mobile, ember.js

I am calculating the idle time of my application using `setTimeout` or 'Later` function. I am getting the issue when the user switch off the screen.

example: when timeout reach 10min, i would like to logout. But when user switch of the screen and opens back at 30min, still not my app logged out because of `timeout` was suspended.

shortly, how can i run my `setTimeout` still the display screen switched off in any of the `mobile` phone?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the user puts their desktop computer to _sleep_ for lunch break, then comes back to your app after 30min?

Comment: I would like to logout by counting the time, When reaches 10min, still the mobile screen switched off ( expire )

Comment: You can try [bg-timer-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bg-timer-helper). I'm not sure how it works for ember, but here not too much code so I think you can take a look, and maybe transplite to ember. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Mobile devices stop every execution of javascript when the screen turns off. On Android you can suppress this, when you're running the website in a custom container application (i.e. build with Cordova).

Comment: The major issues I am facing with iPhone any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to change that behaviour on iOS.